# Trying to dynamically change anchor HREF

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a site that hosts a number of internal reports which are updated every week from various sources, and each year we archive the end-of-year versions.  So we have a folder structure on the server that looks like:

```
Department
  Current
     report1
     report2
     <etc.>
  2013
     report1
     report2
     <etc.>
  2012
  <etc.>
```

I created a select to give the user the option to select the desired period:

```
<select id="period" onchange="UpdateLinks(this)">
  <option value="current" selected>Current</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
</select>
```

The actual links are defined as :

```
<a onclick="EnablePrint();" href="Offshore\Current\NYK_Offshore_Summary.htm" 
id="offshoreSales"  TARGET="report">Sales</a><br>
```

Note that the site is in two frames - these items are displayed in the "menu" side and the reports are displayed in the "report" side, in case that is relevant.

In UpdateLinks() I try to update the hrefs in the anchors to point to the appropriate folder.  According to a number of entries here, this should work, but it is not working for me!:

```
function UpdateLinks(selected) {
    var myURL = 'Offshore\\' + selected.value + '\\';
    alert('New URL prefix: ' + myURL);
    var newURL = myURL + 'NYK_Offshore_Summary.htm';
    document.getElementByID('offshoreSales').href = newUrl;
    newURL = myURL + 'NYK_Offshore_Assets.htm';
    document.getElementByID('offshoreAssets').href = newURL;
}
```

The alert() is happening, and I am seeing the correct value - e.g. "current", or "2013", but the lines

document.getElementByID('offshoreSales').href = newUrl;

are not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misstype on:

```
document.getElementByID('offshoreSales').href = newUrl;
```

Try:

```
document.getElementById('offshoreSales').href = newUrl;
```

Comment: I KNEW it was going to be something stupid like that!  I was glomming on the tag names and double- and triple checking them.  I also paid attention to the case of everything, but overlooked that one.  Thanks